# JSON, jquery, and ajax parsing issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Here's my java script file:

```
$('#addSchoolForm').trigger("reset");

//$(document).ready(function()  {
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        maxWidth:600,
        maxHeight: 350,
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
    });

    $("#addSchool").on("click", function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#addSchoolForm").submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog").dialog("close")
        var postData = jQuery(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AddSchools.php",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data); }
        });   
    });

    $("#editSchool").submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var editData = jQuery(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetSchoolID.php",
            data: editData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){


                var schoolID = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert("success");
                alert(schoolID.name);

                //alert(data["json"]);
                //alert(data); 

                //document.addSchoolForm[sname].value = data[0].name;
                //document.addSchoolForm[abbrev].value = data[abbrev];
                //document.addSchoolForm[abbrev].value = data[0].abbrev;
            }

            alert(schoolID.name); 
        });
        //$("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
})
```

And here's my get schoolID php file

```
<?php
$school_id = $_POST['school_id'];


$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "imagroup123","mytrack");

if(!$db){
    exit("Error in database connection");
    echo("couldn't connect to database");
}
else{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `School` WHERE `SchoolID`='$school_id'";
    $schoolresults = mysqli_query($db,$q);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schoolresults);
    $school["name"] = $row['SchoolLong'];
    $school["abbrev"] = $row['SchoolShort'];

    echo json_encode($school);

    }


?>
```

When I just tested the php file with jsonlint.com I get a correct json object but it's not getting carried through the javascript file. I'm fairly new to this so I'm pretty suck with this problem. I also want to add the data to a form values and then open the dialog form after.

Comment: Which of the two Ajax requests are you asking about? And do the `alert()`s in your Ajax success handlers show anything? Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Since you specified `dataType: 'json'`, you shouldn't call `$.parseJSON()` -- jQuery does that automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
        success: function(data){
            var schoolID = $.parseJSON(data);
```

to:

```
        success: function(schoolID){
```

because `$.ajax` automatically calls `$.parseJSON()` when you specify `dataType: 'json'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the php backend structure that I use all the time:

```
$query = " SELECT * 
           FROM school 
           WHERE SchoolID = $school_id;
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database 1");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $variablestopass = array
    (
           'schoolname' => $row['SchoolLong'],
         'schoolabbrev' => $row['SchoolShort'],
     );
  echo json_encode($variablestopass);}
else
  { echo "Error selection id"; }
```

And here is some js to call it and read it:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
         url: 'thenameofyourfile.php';
        data: {schoolid: schoolid},
        dataType: 'json'
        })
         .done( function() { alert( "Got it!"" );
                             Do other stuff here
                            })
         .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(jqXHR.responseText, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
```

Comment: I got rid of the parse json call but when I try to output the school name the alert box is empty. I'm doing this by: alert(data.schoolname). Is this wrong?

Comment: I made the ".done" callback above very simple as an example (just an alert). To actually call back the "data" you need to put the name you want for the data into the function().  .done( function(data){ alert(data.varname); ...other commands... });. I'll do a complete one, and give you a link in a few minutes.

Comment: Here is a page that I just made with a snippet of code from one of my projects. It explains each line. https://sites.google.com/site/timspqr/home/programs/javascript-code/example-ajax-with-callback